# JQuery Mobile Styling With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

```
$(this).css("background-color", "red");
```

For normal input I style the background RED within my for each input loop which works fine.

But when its a select it doesnt seem to work. The jquery mobile select image still stays the same!

Im using JQuery + JQuery Mobile.

How do i force it to change? Even if its just adding a border?

Comment: Have you looked if the select has a background-image set? If there is a background-image you can set the background-color how much you want, you will not see it as long as the image is not cleared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this was

```
$(element).parent().addClass("inputRequired");
```

Getting the parent of the element(which is the select tag) and adding the required class to the DIV instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily override the styles for every select menus in CSS:

```
div.ui-select span.ui-btn-inner {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    text-align: right;    
}
```

.. or if you want to stick to jQuery:

​`$('.ui-select span.ui-btn-inner').css('background-color', 'blue');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

.. to customize a specific select menu, give your select element an `id` and then to select it with jQuery you'll need to append `-button` to the `id`. That's due to the fact that jQuery Mobile creates multiple elements that you might not know of. So, if you'll give your select menu an id `custom-id` and you want to change its background color, your jQuery should look like this:

```
$('.ui-select #custom-id-button span.ui-btn-inner').css('background-color', 'green');
```

.. and same in CSS:

```
div.ui-select #custom-id-button span.ui-btn-inner {
    text-align: left;    
}
```

**Updated JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/5Bkx9/6/

Comment: Like this answer alot, but how would i do it for only certain selects rather than them all?  

Ive tryed $('#' + id).addClass('customSelect')    and the customselect class is the same as your code above but with backgroud color, as your code ads it to all selects

Comment: okey, i updated my answer and jsfiddle, let me know if you'll need any assistance

Comment: Hey, What a great piece of code, the problem im having now is this:  ive loaded the dom, and when i click a button i want to be able to style the select css, now this doesnt work with our code if i add class or add css and ive tried doing the select element trigger create and still nothing, all help would be very much appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check what `this` is in your execution context. Remember that `this` can be different things for same exact method, depending on target of invocation. It's better to select it explicitly using a selector.

If this is not the problem, check if you have this field styled with `!important` directive added after background color.

To get better analysis of your problem you'll have to give us more information, best replicated in jsfiddle.

Comment: Tried that, i cant important to JS fiddle as this project is way to big